# Meshgrid 2-D Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am wondering if there is a way to do Numpy.meshgrid for a 2D arrays
In my code, I currently have

```
fig=plt.figure(i+3001)

m=Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=38.8908,urcrnrlat=39.1908,llcrnrlon=275.1911,urcrnrlon=275.4911,resolution='h')
px,py=Numpy.meshgrid(x1+360,y1)
X,Y=m(lon+360,lat)


m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
m.fillcontinents(color='grey',alpha=0.1,lake_color='aqua')
m.drawcounties()


#plotting contours

cs=m.contourf(lon+360,lat,bprime1[i],levels=levels,cmap='jet',latlon=True,extend='both')
cs2=m.contour(lon+360,lat,bprime1[i],levels=levels,latlon=True,colors='k',linestyles='solid')

cbar=plt.colorbar(cs)
cbar.add_lines(cs2)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Cloud coverage')

plt.suptitle("CVG 12Z Cloud January 31,2017")
plt.show()
```

But I want to use my lat and lon arrays which both have dimensions ((428),(614)). Whenever I try plugging them in, I get this error:

---

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\jpkal\Documents\JP Kalb-NWA\Experiment4a.py in <module>()
    278 
    279
```

m=Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=38.8908,urcrnrlat=39.1908,llcrnrlon=275.1911,urcrnrlon=275.4911,resolution='h')
--> 280     px,py=N.meshgrid(lon+360,lat)
    281     X,Y=m(lon+360,lat)
    282

C:\Users\jpkal\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.pyc in meshgrid(*xi, **kwargs)
   4113         # Return the full N-D matrix (not only the 1-D vector)
   4114         if copy_:
-> 4115             mult_fact = np.ones(shape, dtype=int)
   4116             return [x * mult_fact for x in output]
   4117         else:

C:\Users\jpkal\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.pyc in ones(shape, dtype, order)
    188 
    189     """
--> 190     a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
    191     multiarray.copyto(a, 1, casting='unsafe')
    192     return a

MemoryError:

Any help would be great.